# Parse String | Filename

Tags: string, file, powershell, parsing, archive

I got files looking like this:

```
aaa-xxx-random1.xml
aaa-xxx-random2.xml
aaa-yyy-random3.xml
aaa-zzz-random4.xml
aaa-zzz-random5.xml
```

How can I parse it in PowerShell to get the second trigram in a variable?

Output expected:

```
xxx
xxx
yyy
zzz
zzz
```

In shell that would be:

```bash
for f in `ls`; do
  echo $f | cut -d "-" -f 2
done
```

The goal of this is to create an archive named by the trigram and move all the XML files from the same family into the archive created.

Comment: ls | %{($_.Name -split '-')[1] }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the filename at hyphens and pick the second element of the resulting array:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -split '-')[1] }
```

or (using aliases)

```
ls | % {($_.Name -split '-')[1]}
```